# How to import multiple excel file into one excel file by using matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-guide

I am a newbie in matlab and get stuck on this matter. I try to make one new file from multiple excel file by using matlab code. It managed to produce the new file. However the file is in a mess and I really do not have any idea how to do it. Here is the code:

```
% Merge multiple XLS files into one XLS file
[filenames, folder] = uigetfile('*.xls','Select the data file','MultiSelect','on');   % gets directory from any folder
% Create output file name in the same folder.
outputFileName = fullfile(folder, 'rainfall.xls');
fidOutput = fopen(outputFileName, 'wt');                            % open output file to write
for k = 1 : length(filenames)
    % Get this file name.
    thisFileName = fullfile(folder, filenames{k});
    % Open input file:
    fidInput = fopen(thisFileName);  
    % Read text from it
    thisText = fread(fidInput, '*char');
    % Copy to output file:
    fwrite(fidOutput, thisText);    
    fclose(fidInput);   % close the input file
end
fclose(fidOutput);
```

I attah the picture showing how mess the resulted data is. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.[image: error]

Comment: The same question over and over with no efforts to get things working. Just look at the profile activity of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use xlsread (or readtable, if you have a recent version of Matlab) instead of fread. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[files,folder] = uigetfile('*.xls','Select Files','MultiSelect','on');
output = fullfile(folder,'rainfall.xls');

c = cell(0,5);

for i = 1:numel(files)
    c_curr = table2cell(readtable(fullfile(folder,files{i}),'ReadVariableNames',false));
    c = [c; c_curr];
end

tab = cell2table(c,'VariableNames',{'MyVar1' 'MyVar2' 'MyVar3' 'MyVar4' 'MyVar5'});

writetable(tab,output);
```

Of course, every file must contain the same number of columns and every column must have the same underlying data type across all the files.

Comment: I don't know how your files look like, so it's hard to say. Anyway all you need to do is to merge the tables you read into a single table within the for loop. Then you move the writetable call outside the loop, at the end of the script, and you change it so that it targets the merging result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Tommaso. I try your code above, but I got an error "Error using cell2table (line 57)
The VariableNames property must contain one name for each variable in the table."

Comment: Sure, I'm not shipping you ready made code. Especially if I have no clues on how your tables look like. Seriously, did you make a single attempt to see what's going on with your code? Because this looks to me like a clear attempty to get yout job done by someone else with zero efforts. And I'm gonna call a moderator intervention here.